# computing 31 bit number / ignoring most significant bit

Tags: c#, binary, computer-forensics

I am working on a piece of software that analyzes E01 bitstream images.  Basically these are forensic data files that allow a user to compress all the data on a disk into a single file.  The E01 format embeds data about the original data, including MD5 hash of the source and resulting data, etc. If you are interested in some light reading, the EWF/E01 specification is [here](http://code.google.com/p/libewf/downloads/detail?name=Expert%20Witness%20Compression%20Format%20%28EWF%29.pdf).  Onto my problem:

The e01 file contains a "table" section which is a series of 32 bit numbers that are offsets to other locations within the e01 file where the actual data chunks are located.  I have successfully parsed this data out into a list doing the following:

```
this.ChunkLocations = new List<int>();
//hack:Will this overflow?  We are adding to integers to a long?
long currentReadLocation = TableSectionDescriptorRef.OffsetFromFileStart + c_SECTION_DESCRIPTOR_LENGTH + c_TABLE_HEADER_LENGTH;
byte[] currReadBytes;
using (var fs = new FileStream(E01File.FullName, FileMode.Open))
      {
      fs.Seek(currentReadLocation, 0);
      for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfEntries; i++)
                {
                    currReadBytes = new byte[c_CHUNK_DATA_OFFSET_LENGTH];
                    fs.Read(currReadBytes,0, c_CHUNK_DATA_OFFSET_LENGTH);
                    this.ChunkLocations.Add(BitConverter.ToUInt32(currReadBytes, 0));
                }
       }
```

The c_CHUNK_DATA_OFFSET_LENGTH is 4 bytes/ "32 bit" number.

According to the ewf/e01 specification, "The most significant bit in the chunk data offset indicates if the chunk is compressed (1) or uncompressed (0)".  This appears to be evidenced by the fact that, if I convert the offsets to ints, there are large negative numbers in the results (for chunks without compression,no doubt), but most of the other offsets appear to be correctly incremented, but every once in a while there is crazy data.  The data in the ChunkLocations looks something like this:

> ```
> 346256
> 379028
> -2147071848
> 444556
> 477328
> 510100
> ```

Where with -2147071848 it appears the MSB was flipped to indicate compression/lack of compression.

QUESTIONS:  So, if the MSB is used to flag for the presence of compression, then really I'm dealing with at 31 bit number, right?
1. How do I ignore the MSB/ compute a 31 bit number in figuring the offset value?
2. This seems to be a strange standard since it would seem like it would significantly limit the size of the offsets you could have, so I'm questioning if I'm missing something?  These offsets to seem correct when I navigate to these locations within the e01 file.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: With 31-bit offsets you can address up to 2 GB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of thing is typical when dealing with binary formats.  As dtb pointed out, 31 bits is probably plenty large for this application, because it can address offsets up to 2 GiB. So they use that extra bit as a flag to save space.

You can just mask off the bit with a bitwise AND:

```
const UInt32 COMPRESSED = 0x80000000;   // Only bit 31 on

UInt32 raw_value = 0x80004000;          // test value

bool compressed = (raw_value & COMPRESSED) > 0;
UInt32 offset = raw_value & ~COMPRESSED;

Console.WriteLine("Compressed={0}  Offset=0x{1:X}", compressed, offset);
```

Output:

```
Compressed=True  Offset=0x4000
```

Comment: Yep, just realized and fixed that. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain what 0x80000000 is?  This is a hexidecimal value of the MSB of a 32 bit unsigned integer?  Also, the offset sizes are concerning to me because we certainly  deal with E01 files that are terabytes in size, so I'm not sure how that is going to work...  Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes. Go into windows calculator, change it to hex, and enter 0x80000000. You'll see that only bit 31 is on.

Comment: I suggest that if you're going to be working with a binary format like this, that you get **very** familiar with hexadecimal. It makes *wayyy* more sense than decimal when you start using it. Also, get very familiar with masking and shifting of integers.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks.  Last question... explain what the ~ operator is... I honestly have never run into that one!

Comment: It is the bitwise "not" operator. It inverts all of the bits. So `0x80000000` becomes `0x7FFFFFFF`. To "mask" bit 31 off, you AND the input value with all of the bits except that one On. The result is, that bit is always off.

Comment: Really though, do some reading. It will help you immensely. ["C bitwise operators"](http://www.google.com/search?q=c+bitwise+operators) provides a plethora of information.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to strip off the leading bit, perform a bitwise and (&) of the value with 0x7FFFFFFF